# How to disable the slow swipe up that shows sideways-swipeable previous screens?

Tags: iphone

I'm using iOS 16.3.1 on an iPhone XR.

Swiping up fast from the bottom takes me to the home page. No problem.

Swiping up slowly from the bottom shows me small versions of screens I've recently had up, which are swipeable sideways. How can I disable this function?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot disable it as it's core part of the UI. It's designed to do that to offer a side-scrollable list of open apps, and flicking an app up will terminate the app if required, eg. something has hung or crashed. If disabled you wouldn't have that functionality.

https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/iphone/iph83bfec492/ios

Comment: The slow swipe up replicates the 'show all open apps' functionality of the original physical Home button double press. Now that iDevices are no longer equipped with real pushable buttons, this is the only way to see (and quit) running apps.